# Interpretation and extrapolation of fixed effects estimators

Tags: interpretation, fixed-effects-model, extrapolation

I am reading a very interesting article by [Ray and Pullabholta (2023)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-42533-7). They start from the observation that adoption of groundwater wells - which are a necessary input to agricultural productivity, and consume quite a lot of energy, meaning that cheaper (than diesel) electricity could induce farmers to adopt - are quite heterogeneous across the country, and that this does not seem to depend on (i) availability of electricity and (ii) availability of ground water (ie, how much you would need to dig / how expensive it would be to dig).

The authors hypothesise that this was due to differential approaches to electrification across the country. There were two phases to Indian electrification. The first phase (pre-2001) concentrated on agricultural electrification, and targeted areas which were able to make the most of green electrification. They notably benefited from more electrical capacity (ground water wells are typically energy intensive) and cheaper tariff. Post 2001, attention was switched to equipping households, with less powerful capacity and more non-flat tarriffs. They refer to the first phase as “non-PC” and the second one as “PC”.

Their empirical strategy is to estimate the effect of being a “PC” district on the number of wells per electrified households, i.e. :
Y it = α elechhit + β elechhit ×PCi + δXit + μi + γt + εi

Where :

- Y it is the number of groundwater wells for district i at time t
- elechhit is the number of electrified rural households for district i at time t
- PC is an indicator variable of the PC status of the district
- Xit is a vector of control variable
- ui are district fixed effects
- yt are time fixed effects

-> In other words, there are using a 2 way fixed effects strategy to study the differential effect of being a PC district on the impact of rural electrification (proxied by number of households electrified) on groundwater irrigation. They find that,"*on average, the electrification of 100 additional households is associated with approximately 2 additional electrified wells among PC districts compared to 16 additional electrified wells among non-PC districts*"

I understand that the FE model would be correct in interpreting the *causal* effect of electrification in "non PC" and "PC" districts. However, I also understand that it would not be correct to say that, had "PC" districts benefited from a similar approach to electrification than "non-PC" districts, they would have benefited from similar outcomes - given the "treatment" (PC vs non-PC) is non-random, and there may be underlying caracteristics that mean that non-PC districts were able to make more of rural electrification.
Is this correct?

Many thanks for your help.